# Resubscribe to Websocket channel in rxjs

Tags: websocket, rxjs

Just getting started with rxjs so sorry if the question is basic. I'm trying to implement a websocket client and subscription in nodejs server-side environment with it. I need to connect to a websocket server, subscribe to a channel by sending a specific message, ingest incoming messages. I want the implementation to reconnect and re-subscribe after a disconnect, thus maintaining a persistent open subscription. I've found how to do reconnect and so far the prototype looks as follows:

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { retry, RetryConfig } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const ws$ = webSocket({
  url: '...',
  WebSocketCtor: WebSocket as any // apparently typings bug
});

// set up reconnects
const retryConfig: RetryConfig = {
  delay: 3000,
};

ws$.pipe(retry(retryConfig));

// subscribe to channel by sending a message
ws$.next({cmd: 'subscribe', channel: 'updates'});

ws$.subscribe({
  next: (msg) => console.log('msg', msg),
  error: (e) => console.error('error', e),
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
});
```

This seems to work so far but after a disconnect it only re-opens the connection and I'm wondering how could I execute custom logic in that case? Specifically here I'd like to re-send the subscription message.

Apart from just an instruction how to do this I'd really appreciate an explanation on why is it so, as rxjs seems to be a bit of a learning curve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the return value of `pipe()`
like this:

```
ws$ = ws$.pipe(retry(retryConfig));
```